# How to define a boolean array as a resource in XML?

Tags: android, arrays, boolean, android-xml, typed-arrays

Using Android's resource system, you can define a string array like this:

```
<string-array name="my_string_array">
    <item>One</item>
    <item>Two</item>
    <item>Three</item>
    <item>Four</item>
</string-array>
```

And an integer array like this:

```
<integer-array name="my_integer_array">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
</integer-array>
```

How do you define a boolean array?

Answer (score 7):

There is no built in type for a boolean array, I believe.  You can probably use a typed array, see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html.  If not, you can implement one via ints the good old C way-  0 is false, non-zero is true.